# Как поменять монитор в Unity во время игры?

Tags: c#, unity3d, монитор

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в Unity сложно поменять монитор, не нарушая работу других мониторов.

```
public void SetMonitor()
{
    if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
    {
        //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("UnitySelectMonitor", _monitorIndex);
        //Screen.SetResolution(Display.displays[_monitorIndex].systemWidth, Display.displays[_monitorIndex].systemHeight, Screen.fullScreen);
        Display.displays[_monitorIndex].Activate(Display.displays[_monitorIndex].systemWidth, Display.displays[_monitorIndex].systemHeight, 60);
        Camera.main.targetDisplay = _monitorIndex;
        Canvas canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
        canvas.targetDisplay = _monitorIndex;
        if (_monitorIndex < Display.displays.Length - 1)
        {
            _monitorIndex++;                
        }
        else
        {                
            _monitorIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("UnitySelectMonitor", 0);
        Screen.SetResolution(Display.displays[0].systemWidth, Display.displays[0].systemHeight, Screen.fullScreen);
        Display.displays[0].Activate();
    }
}
```

Если использовать этот код, то нарушается работа других мониторов.

Comment: Что подразумевается под нарушением работы других мониторов?

Comment: Становится чёрным. Как я понимаю, это из за того что нету камеры, для этого дисплея. У меня одна камера и его надо перемещать по мониторам по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Ну естественно, в документации ясно сказано, что для каждого Дисплея нужна своя камера. А если одну камеру гонять по дисплеям, то остальные не могут отображать.